# How to catch/Capture "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Failed to create SSL connection" while sending message over java vert.x Eventbus

Tags: vert.x, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to use SSL over eventbus. To test the failure case I tried sending message to the eventbus from another verticle in same cluster by passing  some different keystore.

I am getting below exception on console but it is not failing the replyHandler hence my code is not able to detect the SSL exception.

my code:

```
    eb.request("ping-address", "ping!", new DeliveryOptions(), reply -> {
                try {
                    if (reply.succeeded()) {
                        System.out.println("Received reply " + reply.result().body());
                    } else {

                        System.out.println("An exception " + reply.cause().getMessage());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("An error occured" + e.getCause());

                }
            });
```

Exception on console:

```
**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Failed to create SSL connection**
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ChannelProvider$1.userEventTriggered(ChannelProvider.java:109)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:327)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handleUnwrapThrowable(SslHandler.java:1249)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1230)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1271)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:505)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:444)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:283)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:813)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1647)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1615)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1781)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1070)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:896)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:766)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:282)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1329)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1224)
    ... 20 more
```

But handler is failing for timeout after 30 sec.
Timed out after waiting 30000(ms) for a reply. address: __vertx.reply.8419a431-d633-4ba8-a12e-c41fd5a4f37a, repliedAddress: ping-address

I want to capture the SSL exception immediately and handle it. Please guide me how can I Capture/catch this exception.

I tried with below code. Below one is able to handle the exception and I am not getting reply result from called event-bus. Reply result is always null. (value is always null)

```
    MessageProducer<Object> ms = eb.sender("ping-address");

            ms.write("ping!", reply -> {

                if (reply.succeeded()) {
                    reply.map(value -> {
                        System.out.println("Received reply " + value);
                        return reply;
                    });
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No reply");
                    System.out.println("An exception : " + reply.cause().getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch this exception because the Vert.x clustered EventBus implementation  buffers messages when the nodes are not connected together. The message could be sent later if the problem is only temporary.

If you want to be notified earlier, you could set a lower timeout in `DeliveryOptions`.